# Are the Core Web Vitals metrics configurable at build time?

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, web-performance

Is it possible to configure the Core Web Vitals metrics thresholds during build time? or as part of your CI process?

Answer (score 1):

The [Core Web Vitals](https://web.dev/vitals) prescribe a specific set of metrics thresholds and percentiles we believe correspond well to user expectations across a range of devices.

[image]

We encourage using our official thresholds as much as possible. If however, you would like to set custom targets for thresholds (e.g a Largest Contentful Paint performance budget of < 3s), this is possible using [Lighthouse CI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci) and [LightWallet](https://web.dev/use-lighthouse-for-performance-budgets/). Metric targets can be set using [assertions](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#assertmatrix) and a [performance budgets file](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#budgetsfile).

An example of such assertions can be found below:

```js
{
  "ci": {
    "assert": {
      "assertions": {
        "largest-contentful-paint": ["warn", {"maxNumericValue": 3000}],
        "viewport": "error",
        "resource-summary:document:size": ["error", {"maxNumericValue": 14000}],
        "resource-summary:font:count": ["warn", {"maxNumericValue": 1}],
        "resource-summary:third-party:count": ["warn", {"maxNumericValue": 5}]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am now just going through your post history upvoting all the new PSI stuff, keep adding it please, great to know while the documentation catches up!

Comment: I tried to use the thresholds of core web vitals in budget.json with LightWallet, but running lighthouse npm runs a throttled cpu and connection with 3G and Moto G4... Field data web vitals look much better than running with this setup. Do I need to change the throttled setup to meet my user's network conditions better for my lab tests? Am I guessing the connection speed here and than refine it over time? @addyo